# Things for Beginners to Make in Blender

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have recently been learning Blender, and I think that the things that I want to make are a bit too hard for me at the moment. It would be very useful if you could share some ideas for things for me to make to boost my skills. Thanks.

Comment: Voted to close as  this is more apt for a forum (eg [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org)) My 2c worth is, work towards the "things that are a bit too hard for" you at the moment.  Break them down into smaller problems akin to learning the chords of a Hendrix riff...

Comment: See a video tutorial series. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS.  You can follow all the video steps as practice.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pick something that's close to hand that is *familiar* to you - for example, your computer keyboard. If that's too complicated then break it down and concentrate on one part of it - such as a single key. Model that key, capture its shape, texture, color, the letter, shininess of the plastic, etc. Then move on to a whole row of keys (Array modifier?), etc. Start small and work up.